# How to start an Android application when phone boots up if a notification has ocurred while switched off?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to open my android application automatically if there has been a notification from that application.

For example: After booting up up my phone it should automatically launch the application if a notification has occured.

Comment: What kind of notification are you referring to. A notification can't happen if the phone is turned off. You might get a notification, for example, email, once phone has booted and it has done a re-sync

Comment: @Boardy nailed it. Either you are sending a local notification (which won't be triggered if your phone is off), or you are sending it through a network in which it will be received when you get a network connection. If you have a specific trigger (like a time or something) you are getting a notification for you can check it manually on boot but beyond that Android does a pretty good job handling notifications.